# Passing Data to master page and user control from view on button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**My scenario is that In MVC**

my page(view) has both user control(partial view) and master page. i have button in my page(view). while clicking on the button

1) i need to load grid in user control ,
2) i have to take div which is in master page for displaying acknowledge message   like "Successfull loaded".

i saw in some forum to do these two actions seperately but i need to trigger these two in single button click.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript for this.

```
$("#button-id").live('click', function()
{

   $('#master-page-message-id').text('Your message');
   //Send request to server
   $.ajax({
      url: @Url.Action(...),
      error : function(...){
          $('#master-page-message-id').text('Your failure message');
      },

      success: function(data){ 
         $('#master-page-message-id').text('Your success message');
         //update your greed if you get json response
         greed.update(data);
         //OR if you get simple html response
         $("#greed-id").html(data);
      }
   });

});
```

Comment: thanks for reply. but based on user control grid load only i have to show message. if grid inside user control is load successfully then i ll take div from master page then only show success message . if fails i have to display failure message. but above answer is not fulfill my requirement right? it display before grid loads. so any more help?